# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message ''code' must be non-empty'

Tags: php, dropbox

I am trying to display the dropbox folders and files using PHP. Meanwhile I am getting the below error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message ''code' must be non-empty' in D:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\dropbox\Dropbox\Checker.php:59 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\dropbox\Dropbox\WebAuthNoRedirect.php(79): Dropbox\Checker::argStringNonEmpty('code', '') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\dropbox.php(24): Dropbox\WebAuthNoRedirect->finish('') #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\dropbox\Dropbox\Checker.php on line 59

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once "dropbox/Dropbox/autoload.php";
require_once "dropbox/Dropbox/AppInfo.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;
$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("app-info.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");


if(!function_exists("readline")) {
    function readline($prompt = null){
        if($prompt){
            //echo $prompt;
        }
        $fp = fopen("php://stdin","r");
        $line = rtrim(fgets($fp, 1024));
        return $line;
    }
}


$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();
$authCode = \trim(\readline("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n"; 
?>
```

The error is coming from $webAuth->finish() function.From the error i checked the checker.php.There is one function has been defined.That is

```
static function argStringNonEmpty($argName, $argValue)
    {
        if (!is_string($argValue)) self::throwError($argName, $argValue, "string");
        if (strlen($argValue) === 0) throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'$argName' must be non-empty");
    }
```

If i command the condition the error keep on moving to the next next function.Please help how to solve it.

Comment: You’re using `readline`, is this a console application?

Comment: now i'm doing for web application.Console yet to be started

Comment: If you echo `$authCode` you’ll likely find it’s empty and that’s what causing the problem.

Comment: i have authcode which is XXXX....But the variable shows empty

Comment: Remove `readline` and try it. `$authCode = ‘XXXXX’;`

Comment: ya i tried that..i got this error.`Uncaught exception 'Dropbox\Exception_BadRequest' with message 'HTTP status 400`

Comment: That means the request is going through to Dropbox but they’re responding with a 400 error which generally means there is something wrong with the request you’re sending them and it’s not an authentication error as they would be 401 or 403.

Comment: ok then let me check the request and intermediate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my code like below:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;

require __DIR__.'/Dropbox/autoload.php';

$dropboxKey = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$dropboxSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
$appName = 'XXXXXXX/1.0';

$appInfo=new Dropbox\AppInfo($dropboxKey,$dropboxSecret);

//store CSRF token
$csrfTokenStore = new Dropbox\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION,'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');

//Define auth details
$webAuth = new Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo,$appName,'http://localhost/dropboxapi/dropbox_finish.php',$csrfTokenStore);

if(isset($_session['accessToken']))
{
    $client = new Dropbox\Client($_session['accessToken'],$appName,'UTF-8');
    $client->getAccountInfo();
} else {
$authUrl = $webAuth->start();

Header('Location:'.$authUrl);
exit;
}
list($accessToken) = $webAuth->finish($_GET);

$_session['accessToken']=$accessToken;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're the [API v1 Dropbox PHP SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php). Your code looks similar to [the "authorize" example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php/blob/46b9f5731360c37bd755802928a98d095daa4b5d/examples/authorize.php). That sample is built for a command line app, but you're trying to run it as a web app, so it won't work.

Specifically, you're trying to read from stdin (like how the example uses [`\trim(\fgets(STDIN))`](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php/blob/46b9f5731360c37bd755802928a98d095daa4b5d/examples/authorize.php#L45)).

For a web app, you should instead refer to the [web-file-browser example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php/blob/46b9f5731360c37bd755802928a98d095daa4b5d/examples/web-file-browser.php).

In either case, you would need to supply the "authorization code" to complete [the OAuth app authorization flow](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide).

Also, it's important to note that that PHP SDK uses [Dropbox API v1, which is deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/). You should migrate to [Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) instead.

There isn't an official PHP SDK for Dropbox API v2, but you can use a [third party library](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks) or you can call [the HTTPS endpoints](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) themselves.